# How to detect unnecessary Windows\Installer file

Tags: windows, azure, windows-installer, installation, windows-server-2008-r2

i have search a lot to find out How to detect unnecessary Windows\Installer file !

I am sure lot of you have faced this issue previously and solve it somehow.

Now when i look at my ---

```
C:\Windows\Installer
```

directory on Windows Server 2008 R2 i can see it took already 42 GB out if total 126 GB.

Now what i would like to know can i just delete all the files from that `Installer` directory or i have to detect which file can be removed !

Do anyone knows any solution for this issue !

Comment: 42gb is too much.  I'd be suspicious of malware or corruption.  You're question. Is probably off topic, and will probably off topic  and will probably be closed.  I would recommend looking at a tool called Patchcleaner, though I only know of it through hearsay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define unnecessary?

**Specialized system case:** You want the minimum footprint and are willing to sacrifice functionality that you don't expect to use.

If all is well, each the files in C:\Windows\Installer are a local cache of an installed Windows Installer package, patch, transform, etc. They are necessary for uninstallation, [auto-repair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371230) or [on-demand installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369293) to succeed. If you will never need any of those things on these machines (i.e. if you are bringing them up on demand as VMs, and would rebuild them rather than uninstall something), then unless the app itself invokes Windows Installer APIs itself, it may be relatively safe to remove files from C:\Windows\Installer. In addition, you could call the Windows Installer API [MsiSourceListEnum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370403) to find other caches of files that are used for these same purposes. It may be similarly safe (or unsafe) to remove those files.

**More usual case:** You'd rather not rebuild the system

If you suspect there are unreferenced files in that folder left over from prior upgrades or uninstallations, you can try to use Windows Intstaller API calls to verify this. At a very low level, you can call [MsiEnumProducts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370101) (or possibly [MsiEnumProductsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370102)) to find the product codes of all installed products, and [MsiGetProductInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130)/[Ex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370131)(szProduct, INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE, ...) to find its cached .msi file and INSTALLPROPERTY_TRANSFORMS for a list of its transforms. Then [MsiEnumPatches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370099)/[Ex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370100) to find all patch codes and [MsiGetPatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370127)/[Ex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370128) (again with INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE and/or INSTALLPROPERTY_TRANSFORMS) to list the .msp and .mst files it references. In theory, the full set of all files referenced here should match up with the full set of files in C:\Windows\Installer. (Or there are more references to look for...)

(Before you write anything to do this, consider that there are probably apps out there that automate this, or are even smarter about it, such as the one referenced in another answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You could not delete them all.

There is a good [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1050417/how-to-clean-windows-installer-folder-in-windows-10#comment1542371_1050442) about your problem, I test in my lab. It works for me.

Notes: If possible, you had better copy this folder to anther disk (such as E:)